# How to get the type of layer or source in OL3?

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to know how I can get the type of a layer and a source in ol3?

Background: I have a map which the user can modify. The user can (de)activate layer from different sources and I want to extract all the settings the user has made. Like the visible layer, the center point, resolution and more to rebuild the map later.

At the moment I want to collect all the layers and it's sources, but I'm not able to get the layer type. So I don't know if it's a Tile or a Image, etc.

Unfortunately object.constructor.name is an empty string. So any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use instanceof e.g. layer instanceof ol.layer.Tile

Comment: Yes, this works! Thank you! Just to complete the answer: It is not possible to get the name? The only way is to compare it?